# Need a macro that will ask someone for their username so that it can open a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate opening up a closed workbook and extracting some data however I would like a code that would work for multiple people. possibly asking them for their username so that it could open up successfully?

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\username\Documents\New Data.xlsx"
```

I have used something similar to the code and it works when i run the Macro because it is tailored to my specific username however not when someone else try's to run the Macro.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environ("USERNAME")` to get the username or even better `Environ("USERPROFILE")` to get the profile path.

So you can use it like:

```
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\New Data.xlsx")
```

Using the `Environ("USERPROFILE")` has the advantage that it works independently from the Windows version.